# logging tracking id in web filter

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-sleuth

> Blockquote

Running below WebFilter I can see that:

- foo log does not have tracking id
- bar log has tracking id

Why is that?

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 2)
class MyFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono.just(exchange)
            .doOnNext(x -> log.debug("foo"))
            .flatMap(chain::filter)
            .doOnSuccess(x -> log.debug("bar"));
    }
}
```

This question refers to:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1666

Comment: Have to a Configuration or Component annotation top of class. This filter is not bean.

Comment: I updated annotations. Now I realised that when I remove @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 2) tracking id is visible both for foo and bar.

Comment: Using Order annotation I register my bean before TraceWebFilter, that's why tracking is not passed to filter out of the box.
https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/2.2.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebFilter.html#ORDER

Comment: inject this code block into you code. You can see anything? `.flatMap(item -> Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> ctx.get(TraceContext.class).traceId()).doOnNext(trace -> System.out.println(trace)).map(trace -> item))`

Comment: Because TraceContext is stored in reactor context. Logger use this, but I dont like use slf4j logger because MDC information stored in ThreadLocal, just this conecpt now work in reactive approach. See my lib: https://github.com/Numichi/reactive-logger

Comment: it throws java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context does not contain key: class brave.propagation.TraceContext

Comment: You need `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.TraceContext`

Answer (score 0):

Using Order annotation I register my bean **before** TraceWebFilter, that's why tracking is not passed to filter "out of the box".

Documentation for TraceWebFilter:

https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/2.2.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebFilter.html#ORDER